# magento2 set default shipping adress in checkout

Tags: magento2, shipping-address

After checkout page is loaded and customer is loggedin I need to set default shipping adress like a [screen](http://screenshots.collabstar.com/ao/253.png).

Is in magneto2 settings for this or it needs to create extension?

Comment: Screenshot throwing error, Please update

Comment: @ManojDeswal i uploaded screenshot

Comment: Currently , in default magento when a user is logged in and he goes to checkout page..a shipping address ( address defined by user in his/her account) is displayed with check and below that you can add new one . Now please brief me further